# Vault deployment in alive cluster using terraform

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine, vault

I want to deploy vault with a cluster which contains microservices and my vault shouldn't have an external access, and everything should be done using terraform. Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: This question is very general. What have you tried so far? I'd recommend reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for ideas on how to improve this question.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the [Terraform Getting started](https://learn.hashicorp.com/collections/terraform/aws-get-started?utm_source=WEBSITE&utm_medium=WEB_IO&utm_offer=ARTICLE_PAGE&utm_content=DOCS) on how to create Terraform code.
You will need to use the [Google Provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs) to deploy your resources. On that page you can view resources like `kubernetes`, `vault` and lots of others.